# How to bind openssl c binding via CGO in golang

Tags: go, rust, openssl, ffi, cgo

Situation:

- Need to use [EdDSA 448](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve448) JSON web encryption in GoLang, [ref](https://github.com/pratikgajjar/josekit-rs#signing-a-jwt-by-eddsa)
- Couldn't find JWT library which supports this in GoLang
- We are using [jwcrypto](https://jwcrypto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in Python, need similar lib in GO

```json
# Example header
{
  "alg": "ECDH-ES",
  "enc": "A256CBC-HS512",
  "epk": {
    "crv": "X448",
    "kty": "OKP",
    "x": "PNJPrNo7grr4y9m9CaxetWdMWA91aAkBf9xM2bsaJHzcLx5RZWyaBfOMhaGDioPEnOT6alPJ0sE"
  }
}
```

Task:

- Decrypt and verify payload in GO

Actions:

- Used [josekit-rs](https://github.com/hidekatsu-izuno/josekit-rs) in Rust which can solve this
- Created C API via [safer_ffi](https://github.com/getditto/safer_ffi)
- Bind the library via CGO in Golang

Result:

- Whole binding thing works when used simple function (without openssl)

```bash
$ go build . 
# go-jose-kit/jose-kit-ffi
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_AES_ige_encrypt", referenced from:
      openssl::aes::aes_ige::h356a909c3f173638 in libjose_kit_ffi.a(openssl-83ba33f9169f6e94.openssl.2a7d90ad-cgu.15.rcgu.o)
  "_AES_set_decrypt_key", referenced from:
      openssl::aes::AesKey::new_decrypt::h6be3702416d4e43e in libjose_kit_ffi.a(openssl-83ba33f9169f6e94.openssl.2a7d90ad-cgu.15.rcgu.o)
  "_AES_set_encrypt_key", referenced from:
      openssl::aes::AesKey::new_encrypt::heb205e6bc2f989db in libjose_kit_ffi.a(openssl-83ba33f9169f6e94.openssl.2a7d90ad-cgu.15.rcgu.o)
  "_AES_unwrap_key", referenced from:
. . .
. . .
enssl-83ba33f9169f6e94.openssl.2a7d90ad-cgu.13.rcgu.o)
  "_i2d_X509_REQ", referenced from:
      openssl::x509::X509ReqRef::to_der::h5e65612242296419 in libjose_kit_ffi.a(openssl-83ba33f9169f6e94.openssl.2a7d90ad-cgu.13.rcgu.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems CGO is unable to find external methods (symbols) used by rust binary.

Tried to create static lib but it isn't possible to link `openssl` within rust compiled object.

In main.go file have added these headers.

```golang
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib -L ./target/debug -l jose_kit_ffi -l pthread -l dl -lm
#include "./jose_kit_ffi.h"
```

```bash
$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/{USERNAME}/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/{USERNAME}/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/{USERNAME}/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/{USERNAME}/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.1/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.18.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.1"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/{PATH}/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/8l/_xp4ll7n4c3dqjxrs8klhkqh0000gn/T/go-build3058634703=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it via creating dylib instead of static lib.

```ini
[package]
name = "jose-kit-ffi"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[lib]
# crate-type = ["staticlib"] -> Doesn't work
crate-type = ["dylib"] -> 
# ^ It won't include openssl symbols in binary.

[dependencies]
safer-ffi = { version = "0.0.10", features = ["proc_macros"] }
josekit = "0.8.1"
serde_json = "1.0"


[features]
c-headers = ["safer-ffi/headers"]
```

Result

```bash
go run .
2022/08/21 22:19:14 Hello, from GO!
JwkSecret { priv_key: "--", pub_key: "--" }
Encrypted JWT: eyJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwiZXBrIjp7Imt0eSI6Ik9LUCIsImNydiI6Ilg0NDgiLCJ4IjoiTmdjRlE4bFY3WWtjUWMtNXR6RlhuUnZvcEI0NlZVTnhPWHFKajgwSzNLQnR4YWh1al9zM3ZNRVY4WVA0cnVvNkttS0FNR0FCN1M4In0sImFsZyI6IkVDREgtRVMifQ..q9BgTEh2UPjiSgLNfu0BTw.rLDyrLQYwtWpi4Qyo43csmERW-VNXowQQBPmqu7zj7U.epX8cMdNA9o9xzMTVdaxJALdtgruVyox5JaPYxKpwZ8
Some("eyJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwiZXBrIjp7Imt0eSI6Ik9LUCIsImNydiI6Ilg0NDgiLCJ4IjoiTmdjRlE4bFY3WWtjUWMtNXR6RlhuUnZvcEI0NlZVTnhPWHFKajgwSzNLQnR4YWh1al9zM3ZNRVY4WVA0cnVvNkttS0FNR0FCN1M4In0sImFsZyI6IkVDREgtRVMifQ..q9BgTEh2UPjiSgLNfu0BTw.rLDyrLQYwtWpi4Qyo43csmERW-VNXowQQBPmqu7zj7U.epX8cMdNA9o9xzMTVdaxJALdtgruVyox5JaPYxKpwZ8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hei, I suggest u using github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4 lib. this popular i think. And Recommended as the one in https://jwt.io or if u need more, u can see another recommendation library JWT in there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for resp. We can't use any of popular golang libraries because none of them supports JWE with `ECDH-ES+A256KW`

Comment: https://github.com/temporary00/eddsa try to look in this. maybe help u

Comment: It might do the job but still need to implement JWE on top of it. Cloudflare also has open source [lib-circl](https://github.com/cloudflare/circl) for signature and verification.